# Разница времени в формате HH:mm:ss:SSS

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста как вычислить разницу времени типа String, 
например 12:07:32.434 и 11:01:11.413
Должно получиться 01:06:21.021
БОЛЬШОЕ спасибо за отзывы!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конвертируйте время из строки в LocalTime и сравнивайте.

```
 LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.parse( "12:07:32.434" );
 LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.parse( "11:01:11.413" );

 System.out.println( t1.minus( t2.toNanoOfDay(), ChronoUnit.NANOS )) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что приходит в голову - это преобразовать строку в Date, это описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451016/convert-string-in-time-to-time-object-without-date/25458538), а затем получить получить разницу, это описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances). Затем выполнить обратную конвертацию, [long -> Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487460/converting-long-to-date-in-java-returns-1970) и [Date -> String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string)

Comment: не надо так делать, в java.time есть все что нужно